# How to disable Execute-only Memory globally with gradle?

Tags: android, mobile, crash, samsung-mobile, android-10.0

After migrating the project to AndroidX, app started crashing with error `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x77b6371ff8 in tid 5378`. Crashes on Samsung device with Android 10. Document says we can disable XOM with these commands.

`// Android.mk LOCAL_XOM := false`

`// Android.bp cc_binary { // or other module types ... xom: false, }`

But my app is not a native app (NDK). Is there any way to disable XOM in gradle? Or is there any other solution to fix this error?